# How do JUnit and TestNG work? I wonder the theory

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I am new in Java programming. I started to learn java recently.  Everything works fine and my question is not about a code. I wonder mechanisms, how does JUniut "understand" how to use classes of my program?

Normal program has a flow and it starts from Main()... and what is about JUnit? has it its own flow?   Could you please explain it to me?
What is a program on JUnit? what does make it work?  netbeans or maven\ant??
Can I create unit tests without maven\ant?
Are there some design patterns? I would like to read about it.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every Java application you launch from the command line or from a script will have a main class and it will have a `main()` method.*

It's just that in the case of JUnit and TestNG these main classes are part of the JUnit and TestNG libraries themselves. That main class in turn is responsible for loading your unit test classes, calling your test methods, then produce a report.

You can download the source code for both libraries and check yourself.

And you can read more on how the Java Virtual Machine starts up [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html).

*Applets running in a browser appear to have a different entry point, hence the roundabout wording. Though even behind an applet container there is a `main()` method somewhere.